# Divs with position: sticky have the wrong top after transform: scale

Tags: css, position, css-transforms, sticky

In my Next.js app, I have a component that users can pinch to zoom in or out of.
The problem is that when zooming in or out, the divs with `position: sticky` and `top: 0px` are no longer stuck to the top of the screen.

What can I do to preserve the transform behavior while fixing the divs to the top of the screen?

In the parent div, we use the zoom value to scale the div like so:

```
    <div
      style={{
        transform: `scale(${zoom})`,
        transformOrigin: 'top left',
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
```

One of the child divs has properties

```
      <div className="z-20 sticky top-0">
        <ItemCard item={cols[idx]} />
      </div>
```

I expected the ItemCards to be stuck to the top of the screen, but instead they moved around like shown [here](https://youtu.be/bJMEpL4rxAQ?t=941).